# change colour kendo ui button

Tags: button, kendo-ui, telerik

I need to change a color for button in Kendo ui product. Please advise. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action='@Url.Action("Index")' style="width:45%">
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:12px" })     
                    .Name("FileUpload")
                    .Multiple(false)
                    .Events(ev => ev.Success("onSuccess"))
        )
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Import" style="height:33px; font-size:14px" class="k-button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to change k-button class but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Kendo UI Web framework and there is no button widget defined in it. Button widget is only available for kendo UI Mobile framework. k-button class wont work as Kendo ignores the  element. So you need to style your button using CSS or inline styling as done normally. `<input type="submit" style="background:red">`

Comment: This is now a Kendo UI Web button control. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/button/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zacharydl/4QezZ/) of a custom CSS class to accomplish this. You basically have to handle a gradient and a hover that removes it. I have cases where I disable buttons by appending the `.k-state-disabled` class. If you don't need the ability to disable your buttons, remove the third style block.

```
.primary {
    background-color: #64a1d5;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #64a1d5, #428bca);
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #428bca;
    min-width: 70px;
}

    .primary:hover {
        background-color: #428bca;
        color: #fff;
        border-color: #428bca;
    }

    .primary.k-state-disabled, .primary.k-state-disabled:hover {
        background-color: #8dc5e1;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Web Kendo UI Framework does not expose the button widget, but you can use it by defining a link with class k-button:

```
<a id="btnSubmit" class="k-button" value="Import" />
```

Now you can style any way you want using the a.k-button selector:

```
a.k-button {
   height: 33px;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #2c2c2c;
}
```

Comment: Including: a.k-button.k-state-active {...} and a.k-button:hover {...}